# Postman throwing error on API testing in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

I've been trying to test an api in springboot but failed to fetch the data in postman. This is what i've done.

This is entity

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity

public class Division {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String division;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "division", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<District> districts = new ArrayList<>();


}
```

This is repository

```
public interface DivisionRepository extends JpaRepository <Division, String> {
}
```

This is Service

```
@Service
public class DivisionService {
    @Autowired
    DivisionRepository divisionRepository;
    public List <Division> getAllDivision(){
        return divisionRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

This is controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/division")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080", allowCredentials = "true")
public class DivisionController {

    @Autowired
    DivisionService divisionService;

    @GetMapping
    List<Division> getAlldivisions(){

        return divisionService.getAllDivision();
    }
}
```

[this is the table that I want to fetch in postman in JSOn format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8djjg.png)

Using a GET request, I put the URL **http://localhost:8080/division** but it's throwing *Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080*

What's the wrong with my code?

Comment: If you set `DivisionController` to just return "Hello world", do you then also get an ECONNREFUSED? (What I'd like to find out is, if it is the Controller that's the problem, or if the problem originates deeper in the code - for example the connection to the database).

Comment: Hi @S.L.Barthisoncodidact.com, this is interesting! It returned hello world in the postman.

Comment: Good! Seems the Controller itself is set up right, then. I'm guessing the problem is in the connection with the database. I'm not sure if I can be of much more help here. One thing you could try is to use an in-memory database and see if that works. Or see if you can reach the database from Postman directly. It could be a firewall block, or something like that. Good luck!

Comment: `but it's throwing Error:`, where did you see this error ? is there any exception on the spring log/output ? What returns the local browser for this URL ?

Comment: @PeterMmm, yes. That's a huge and huge exception whenever I press send button in postman.

Comment: @S.L.Barthisoncodidact.com, My previous projects work fine and I tested just now. I assume that the problem might lie in the entity file. The id is string and it's the PK. Do you think it might be a problem?

Comment: So, edited your question and add the first lines of the Exception.

Comment: @PeterMmm, two exceptions were found.


1. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed.


2. ERROR 17360 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException

Comment: Let's do a step back. Forget Postman for a moment. Run your service and visit http://localhost:8080/division in a browser on the same host where the spring app is running. What do you get in the browser ? post the first **few** lines of the Exception and stack trace (if any) into your question. And remove this `@CrossOrigin`annotation.

Comment: @PeterMmm, in the browser it throws 
[{"id":"bar","division":"Barishal","districts":[{"id":"bar1","district":"Barisal","division":{"id":"bar","division":"Barishal","districts":....... infinite times.

Comment: There is another issue with the code and it is a multiple-table relationship. But I want to avoid it here as the discussion is getting lengthy. I would like to request, could you please look at my https://github.com/Mahadijava/dynamic_dropdown  file and I believe that once you look at the whole picture, you'll get it. It is provided with Mysql database file name bangladesh.sql.

Comment: You have a recursive JSON mapping. Read here: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

Comment: Thank you @PeterMmm, you really saved me. I want to select is as the right answer but don't see anything like "Select it as the correct answer".